# Am I using the modulo operator incorrectly?

Tags: python, syntax, operators, modulo

If my understanding is correct, 5 % 5 should equal 0. However when i run this code:

```
endless = 0
while endless == 0:
    n = int(input("Provide a number here:  "))
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    while count < n:
        if 1+count % 3 == 0 | 1+count % 5 == 0:
            sum += 1 + count
        count += 1
        if count >= n:
            print(sum)
```

It always returns 0, which implies that 1+count % 3 or 1+count % 5 never equals 0. What did i miss?

EDIT:
I seem too have missed fundamental maths somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use bitwise OR, and use paranthesis ([operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence))!

Try:

```
(1+count) % 3 == 0 or (1+count) % 5 == 0:
^       ^          ^^ ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator priority of `%` is the same as `/` and higher than `+`, that means:

```
1+count % 3 == 1 + (count % 3)
```

which can never be `0` since modulo returns a value between 0 and 2.